# Can I make it so scroll bars extend to the very edge of the screen in lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, scrollbar

My problem with the scroll bars in lubuntu (15.10) is that they are set slightly away from the edge, so you have to be careful when placing your mouse on them, instead of just whooshing your mouse over and it stops when it hits the edge of the screen and then you're on the bar. Same with the tool bar at the bottom of the screen, set away from the edge by a pixel or two. Is there a setting which changes this? Or has someone written a script? Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm all very new to Linux as a whole and I'm enjoying it a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a while trying to figure this out, I've managed to fix both problems.

The scroll bar sitting away from the edge of the screen and annoying the hell out of me can be simply fixed by changing themes to one which simply doesn't do that. I'd recommend "Mist" because it also has arrows at the end of the bar.

- Go menu > preferences > Customise Look and Feel and then try out the different options under the "widget" tab

The task bar was a little more tricky to figure out, but ultimately just as simple to do:

- Right click the panel, click "Panel settings" and under "Geometry" change "icon size" to be the same as "Height"

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not the answer you are looking for, but just chose a different desktop theme and that should took care of it. If not, let me know, its been a while since i have used lubuntu, I would have to re-look at everything to further help out.

Comment: Thank you! This set me on the right path, I've sorted the scrollbar problem. My mistake was to think that the customising the look-and-feel only changed the visuals without changing anything practically. I'm now using "Mist" which comes with the original install of lubuntu.

Comment: Now to figure out how to do the same with the menu tray. It's particularly frustrating, because I can actually see the gap between it and the edge of the screen! It seems bizarre that it would be there by default.